# ICMP ECHO REPLY is not being SNATed correctly

Tags: networking, iptables, openvpn, ubuntu-14.04, masquerade

I am trying to provide L3 connectivity between two remote LAN networks (10.0.0.0/24, 10.0.1.0/24) using OpenVPN with the following setup:

```
+----------------+  +---------------------+  +---------------------+
|VM A            |  |VM B (OpenVPN Server)|  |VM C (OpenVPN Client)|
|eth0:10.0.0.5/24|--|eth0:10.0.0.4/24     |  |eth0:10.0.1.4/24     |
+----------------+  |tun0:10.8.0.1/32     |==|tun0:10.8.0.2/32     |
                    +---------------------+  +---------------------+
```

Providing following IP table rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.4
```

Pinging VMC->VMA(10.0.0.5) ICMP echo request's IP is SNATed correctly on VM B:

```
VM-B# tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
09:27:36.170555 IP 10.0.0.4 > 10.0.0.5: ICMP echo request, id 4049, seq 2, length 64
09:27:36.171201 IP 10.0.0.5 > 10.0.0.4: ICMP echo reply, id 4049, seq 2, length 64
```

But pinging VMA->VMC(10.0.1.4) echo reply's IP is NOT SNATed on VM B:

```
VM-B# tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
09:33:31.791095 IP 10.0.0.5 > 10.0.1.4: ICMP echo request, id 6590, seq 2, length 64
09:33:31.795299 IP 10.0.1.4 > 10.0.0.5: ICMP echo reply, id 6590, seq 2, length 64
```

which in my case results in dropping the packet by other underlying (VM's host machine) anti-spoofing iptables rules to prevent IP spoofing.

I don't understand why is the ICMP echo reply packet not being SNATed properly and how to make it happen. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ICMP echo-reply is the return half of a connection, and they're handled differently, for a reason.

Firstly, if you *did* manage to do what you want, you'd break PING: VMA would send an ICMP echo-request to `10.0.1.4`, but get an ICMP echo-reply (PONG) from `10.0.0.4`.  It would not associate that PONG with the PING previously sent, so you'd see 100% packet loss (plus gratuitous PONGs).

The way to handle SNAT on returns is to do DNAT on outbounds, and let the NAT tidy-up logic handle with de-NATting the return half traffic.  But you can't do that here, because if you DNAT everything coming into VMB's eth0 to `10.0.0.4`, you won't be able to talk to VMB any longer.

So the right thing to do is to fix the underlying problem, and make your host's martian-detection logic fit with your actual IP addressing scheme.